# extract only duplicate value from multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array like this

```
 $non_unique_zip

          [0]->[0]91390
               [1]ca
               [2]1

          [1]->[0]91391
               [1]ca
               [2]1

          [2]->[0]91392
               [1]ca
               [2]1

           [3]->[0]91390
                [1]ca
                [2]2

           [4]->[0]91394
                [1]ca
                [2]2
```

so basically array has elements where arra[n][0] is zipcode and array[n][2] is buyer_id.
now out of this, i just want the zipcodes which have multiple buyers. so the only thing I want to extract is

```
[0]->[0]91390
     [1]ca
```

since 91390 is the only zipcode which has buyer as 1 and 2.
I tried

```
$result = array();
$first = $non_unique_zip[0];
for($i=0; $i<count($non_unique_zip); $i++){
    $result = array_intersect ($first, $non_unique_zip[$i]);
    $first = $result;
}
```

but it just gives error undefined offset.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Garima do you actually care about the state (eg: `ca`) or do you just want the zip codes that repeat?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use an array that keeps track of the zip codes that have already been encountered before. Then when you get a zip that's in that array, you know it's a duplicate.

```
$zips = array();
$result = array();
foreach ($non_unique_zip as $e) {
    $code = $e[0];
    if (isset($zips[$code])) { // duplicate, so add to $result
        $result[$code] = array($code, $e[1]);
    } else {
        $zips[$code] = true; // first time, add it to $zips
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `$records` your starting array, here is a way to get the zips with 3 lines of code:

```
//array whose keys are zips, and values are # of occurances
$zips = array_count_values(array_column($records,0));

//filter keeps only zips which occur more than once.
$zips = array_filter($zips,function($n){return $n>1;});

//if you only need the zips, you're done! they are the keys
$zips = array_keys($zips);
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/Bj7JO)

Answer (score -1):

Use `array_walk` like so:

```
    <?php

        $non_unique_zip = [
            [91390, "ca"],
            [91391, "ca"],
            [91392, "ca"],
            [91390, "ca"],
            [91394, "ca"],
        ];

        $unique_zip = [];
        $duplicates = [];

        array_walk($non_unique_zip, function($data) use(&$unique_zip, &$duplicates){
            if(!in_array($data, $unique_zip)){
                $unique_zip[] = $data;
            }else{
                $duplicates[] = $data;
            }
        });


        var_dump( $duplicates );
        // PRODUCES::
        array (size=1)
          0 =>
            array (size=2)
              0 => int 91390
              1 => string 'ca' (length=2)


        var_dump( $unique_zip );
        // PRODUCES::
        array (size=4)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => int 91390
              1 => string 'ca' (length=2)
          1 => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => int 91391
              1 => string 'ca' (length=2)
          2 => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => int 91392
              1 => string 'ca' (length=2)
          3 => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => int 91394
              1 => string 'ca' (length=2)
```

Comment: That's returning all the unique zips, not just the zips with multiple buyers.

Comment: Where are the buyer numbers in your array?